# Can a smart contract in Go language be deployed to azure ethereum consortium blockchain? If yes, how?

Tags: contract-development

I have a smart contract(created in GO language) working for IBM bluemix blockchain. This work was done by a separate team.I need to create a replica of the same using a Azure Ethereum blockchain. I am very new to the blockchain and smart contract technologies. Can I use the same smart contract(Go language) for the Azure Ethereum consortium blockchain? If yes, how will I compile and deploy it?